# Combine 2 objects to 1 object with animations

Tags: animation, edit-mode

I have two objects, and 1 of them has animation. I want to combine them with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, but when combined, the animation is deleted.

How can I reduce 2 objects to 1 object while keeping the animation ?

Comment: Just select the object without animation, then the one with animation before pressing Shift J

Answer (score 1):

As Nascent says you can select the object with animation at last, you can also join and the action will still be available in the *Dope Sheet > Action Editor* and look into the dropdown menu:

[image]

But your question is a bit more complex as you want to join a lid to a box object and I guess you want the lid to keep its animation, and you don't want the box to move. In that case you have 2 solutions:

- Don't join the 2 objects, just parent the lid to the box (select the lid, shift select the box, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent). When you'll move the box, the lid will follow, and it is still animated.
- Join the 2 objects. In that case you can't count on your current animation anymore as it will move both the lid and the box, but you can use bones to animate the part of the object you want.

Comment: I did what you said, when I do shift + j, I don't get any results. The objects are still 2.
Problem image : https://i.hizliresim.com/4WIp90.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you join, there will be only one object at the end. But your situation is a bit more complicated than what you explained at the beginning, if you want to join the lid to the box, the animation will animated box + lid as one object, is it what you want? It looks like your animation is just the lid rotating. In that case you have 2 solutions: keep 2 separate objects (but you can parent the lid to the box) or make one object and use a bone to animate the lid

Comment: yes, this is what I want. I do not have much information about this subject. Can you share a sample tutorial video?

Comment: well, the simplest solution would be to parent the lid to the box: Select the lid, then the box, press Ctrl P, now your 2 objects are still separate but if you move the box, the lid moves along, which is probably what you want. Making one unique object and using bones is probably useless if the parent solution is ok

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but when we look from windows 3d application, there is no problem in animation while unreal engine also causes problems. What is the reason?
Image : https://i.hizliresim.com/S9YAO1.jpg

Comment: could you please share your file? It may be because of some scales or rotations that you need to apply? Use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here : https://pasteall.org/blend/9e57c50b94cf47fa9cd55f0fa3b60f61

Comment: there must be problems with scales and rotations, the best would probably be to close the actions you've created for the box and for the lid (go in the Dope Sheet, switch to Action Editor, click on the X on the right of the action name), apply the scale and rotation of both the 2 objects, then parent animate the lid again

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you very much. It was my first question in the forum. You helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: great, you're welcome  ;)